# Expression invalid null pointer

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am having some issues with my program, what I want to do is generate a `md5` password which then save it to a text file and this part is not working for me, ("Expression invalid null pointer") any help would be greatly appreciated.

## C++ Visual Studio 2015

## main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <istream> 
#include <string> 
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include "s_encrypt.h"
#include "encrypt_copy.h"


using namespace std;




int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string password = "";

    cout << "Please enter a password to be encrypted\n";
    getline(cin, password);


    cout << "MD5 Encryption of " << password << " " << "is this" << " " << md5(password);

    cout << "Saving MD5 generated password to text file";

    std::string p = md5(password);

    CopyEncryptedPw(p);

    return 0;

}
```

## encrypt_copy.cpp

```
#include <istream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "encrypt_copy.h"

using namespace std;

std::string CopyEncryptedPw(std::string pass)

{
    fstream outfile;

    outfile.open("C:\encrypted_pass.txt", ios::out);
    outfile << pass;
    return 0;
}
```

## encrypt_copy.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef ENCRYPT_H
#define ENCRYPT_H


std::string CopyEncryptedPw(std::string pass);

#endif
```

[image]

Comment: On what line does the program fail?

Comment: Most likely, `outfile.open()` call fails. For one thing, `"C:\encrypted_pass.txt"` should be `"C:\\encrypted_pass.txt"` (note double backslash). Read about escape sequences in your favorite C++ textbook. And check library calls for failures.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik or just remember that forward slash works as directory separators in Windows too.

Comment: I took a screen shot of the error. @cdhowie

Comment: I tried the suggestion with double backslashes with the same results @IgorTandetnik

Comment: @Snowman41288 Look at my answer for the string issue.  You should have also pressed "Retry" so that you could see where the corruption occurs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

**Issue 1:**

```
outfile.open("C:\encrypted_pass.txt", ios::out);
```

If we assume that your OS is Windows, this should be:

```
outfile.open("C:\\encrypted_pass.txt", ios::out);
```

Also, the forward slash can be used for the standard stream functions:

```
outfile.open("C:/encrypted_pass.txt", ios::out);
```

---

**Issue 2:**

You're returning 0 for a function that is supposed to return a `std::string`.

```
std::string CopyEncryptedPw(std::string pass)
{
    //...
    return 0;  // <-- This is bad
}
```

This code exhibits undefined behavior on return, since what will happen is that a 0 is assigned to the `std::string` return value, and assigning 0 to a `std::string` is undefined behavior.

Either return a string type (or a type that is convertible to a `std::string`), or return `int`:

```
int CopyEncryptedPw(std::string pass)
{
    fstream outfile;
    outfile.open("C:\\encrypted_pass.txt", ios::out);
    outfile << pass;
    return 0;
}
```

You could also have a `void` function that doesn't return anything, but you probably want an `int` return value for example, to return an error code (or OK indicator).

Comment: 0 **or any integer**??? Why would that be? The problem is passing a nullpointer where a null-terminated string is expected.

Comment: You're right.  Changed answer to explicitly state 0.

Comment: To clarify a bit, returning 0 from a function that returns `std::string` will cause the returned value to be constructed using the `std::string(char const *)` constructor overload, passing in 0 as the argument.  This constructor is documented to invoke undefined behavior if a null pointer is passed in, and as we know, 0 implicitly converts to any pointer type as the null pointer.  tl;dr: `return 0;` in this context is doing the same thing as `return std::string(nullptr);`, which is UB.